# Help with arrow diagram

Tags: diagrams

Is there a way to draw the following diagram using only the default provided packages?

[image]

I've tried replicating it using TikZ and the Automata library, but I had issues with placing the arrows like in the picture. I'm open and looking for a valid alternative that allows me to exactly (if possible) place the following arrows as such.

Thank you all.

P.S.: if you would like to post an answer to this question with code, you can put your own placeholder text in it instead of the stuff in the image. The only thing I need are the three elements (vectors) connected between these arrows in this arrangement.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Please post the code you tried, even if it does not produce the desired outcome.

Comment: Would having a look at flow charts get you started. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)—Creating_Flowcharts

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility using `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{mycircle/.style={circle, fill=#1!20, minimum size=8mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5cm]
|[mycircle=red]| \vec{R}\arrow[r, text=red, "\textup{derivazione}", shift left=3mm]\arrow[rr, bend right=60, looseness=.5, text=red, "\textup{doppia derivazione}"']
    & |[mycircle=orange]| \vec{v}\arrow[r, text=red, "\textup{derivazione}", shift left=3mm]\arrow[l, text=blue, "\textup{integrazione}", shift left=3mm] 
    & |[mycircle=blue]| \vec{a}\arrow[l, text=blue, "\textup{integrazione}", shift left=3mm]\arrow[ll, bend left=75, looseness=.8, text=blue, "\textup{doppia integrazione}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Also, sorry for not sending my original source. I've lost it while copy-pasting other stuff in my latex document. I'll keep it in mind for future questions.